# Manually create List of entities where the entity has foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 application. There is a database but for now I can't add data to it, but still the project is using Entity Framework and Database first, so I have the entities created in my solution. What I want is to create a List of Entities which should represent the result from a query to the Database once it's free for use.

This is the entity created by the EF :

```
    namespace DataAccess
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class MCS_DocumentFields
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public int RowNo { get; set; }
            public int ColumnNo { get; set; }
            public Nullable<bool> IsRequired { get; set; }
            public string QuestionText { get; set; }
            public string FieldValue { get; set; }

            public virtual MCS_ContentTypes MCS_ContentTypes { get; set; }
            public virtual MCS_Documents MCS_Documents { get; set; }
            public virtual MCS_Fields MCS_Fields { get; set; }
        }
    }

I have Extensions so this is the extension for this entity :

namespace DataAccess
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MCS_DocumentFieldsMetaData))]
    public partial class MCS_DocumentFields : BaseEntity
    {

    }

    internal sealed class MCS_DocumentFieldsMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        public int RowNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ColumnNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally in my controller I create the List which holds instances of `MCS_DocumentFields` :

```
 List<MCS_DocumentFields> DocumentData = new List<MCS_DocumentFields>()
            {
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 1, RowNo = 1, ColumnNo = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "alabala", FieldValue = ""},
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 2, RowNo = 1, ColumnNo = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "", FieldValue = "yes"},
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 3, RowNo = 2, ColumnNo = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "alabala", FieldValue = "yes"},
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 4, RowNo = 3, ColumnNo = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "alabala", FieldValue = "yes"},
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 5, RowNo = 4, ColumnNo = 1, IsRequired = false, QuestionText = "alabala", FieldValue = "no"},
                new MCS_DocumentFields {Id = 6, RowNo = 4, ColumnNo = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "alabala", FieldValue = "no"},
            }
```

The problem is that this - `public virtual MCS_Fields MCS_Fields { get; set; }` represents `FiedlId` FK in the database and I need to add the value to this in my `DocumentData` for every record. However I can't use `FieldId` directly, instead I can use the Entity `MCS_Fields` but I don't know how to proceed from there. Obviously just typing `MCS_Fields.Id` doesn't work... so how can I simulate this in my List?

Comment: I figured it out : just add at the end of every instance this: `MCS_Fields = new MCS_Fields{MCS_QuestionTypes = new MCS_QuestionTypes{Id = 1}}`. I have one extra Entity but this is the way it works. Then to retrieve the value - `DocumentData[i].MCS_Fields.Id`.